# WebView targeting 29 not showing content

Tags: android, webview, android-10.0

I have an app with this up-to-date declaration:

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 29
    ...
```

And also I have few `WebView`s in app - full sized `Activity`, `Fragment` version and also an ad which is fixed size (lets say 300x300dp, centered horizontally) `View` placed on list with native widgets. This last one is not loading anymore after target update (only this one, all other are working), but when I change (revert) just this on line:

```
    targetSdkVersion 28
```

it is working as before update. Whole `WebView` setting for this ad looks like this:

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.ad_banner_webview);
webView.setLayerType(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 19 ?
            WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE : // on older devices non-fullactivity webview is blinking/glitching
            WebView.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
final String userAgent = AppInfo.getInstance(webView.getContext()).getUserAgent();
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgent);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setTextZoom(100);
webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        if (!isDummy)
            webViewContainer.setTag(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
});

//disabling long touch - text not selectable
webView.setOnLongClickListener(v -> true);
webView.setLongClickable(false);
webView.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);
```

Note that on API 19 (lowest supported) `webView` has `setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE)` called and is working always, no matter of targeting...

Question is simple: what is the reason of this behavior and how to fix this?

I was looking in [DOCs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-10) what may changed my app behavior after target update, but there is no word about `WebView`. Also I've found some hidden info about changes in rendering by `WebView` - [so-called Trichrome](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/android_webview/docs/channels.md), but still don't have idea is it related - I don't have any special log/output with any clue and issue is present from 5.0 to 10, on these I'm using `LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

turning out that way of loading content matters a lot... we have `loadUrl`, `loadData` and `loadDataWithBaseURL` methods in `WebView` and all three are treating given input data in a very different ways

in my case problematic was `loadData` with code similar to this:

```
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0"><div class='banner-wrap'>        
<iframe class='html5-iframe' src='https://example.com/html5/123.html#https://example-ads.com/deliver/ad.php?param=123__destination=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.anothersite.com%2F' width='300' height='300'>
</iframe>    
<a href='https://example.com/html5/123.html#https://example-ads.com/deliver/ad.php?param=123__destination=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.anothersite.com%2F' target='_blank'>
</a>    
</div></body>
```

note that url is html escaped (% present), but with one exception: the **#** in url. with this character present in URL iframe won't load content... and was loading when targeting <=28. when using `loadUrl` giving this with-#-url everything works fine no matter of target. but I'm fitting into already exisiting ad distribution system and it won't be changed for app. also I think that manipulating given HTML code to extract `src` url isn't a proper way (system may be upgraded somehow someday)...

my solution for now is to use `base64` and set same encoding for `WebView`:

```
String base64version = Base64.encodeToString(htmlData.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
webView.loadData(base64version, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "base64");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution man! I've been behind this thing for a long time now.

Comment: So you load the base64Version? how come this works? I suppose you don't want to show a base64 string in the webView? I tried this and the result is the whole text encoded :S

Comment: HTML data is encoded with Base64, but `webView.loadData(` method is determining `"base64"` in last attr. works well for me

Answer (score 0):

> I had the same issue while updating version SDK 29. I change my code it is working for SDK version  29

```
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebViewClientImpl webViewClient = new WebViewClientImpl(this);
    webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,html_content,"text/html","UTF-8",null);
```